# How do I add percentages to my sales funnel in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, diagram

Faced with the problem of displaying percentages on the sales funnel in plotly.
I have the following table:

| month | visit_site_month | reg_month | application | game |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09 | 778 | 186 | 40 | 2 |
| 2022-10 | 843 | 219 | 68 | 21 |
| 2022-11 | 786 | 195 | 66 | 43 |
| 2022-12 | 805 | 200 | 65 | 47 |
| 2023-01 | 852 | 215 | 77 | 63 |
| 2023-02 | 32 | 9 | 3 | 3 |

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Create a list of funnel steps
steps = [
    go.Funnel(
        name='Visits',
        x=merged_month_df['visit_site_month'],
        y=merged_month_df['month'],
        textposition='inside',
        textinfo="value+percent initial",
        marker={'color': '#3b78e7'}
    ),
    go.Funnel(
        name='Registrations',
        x=merged_month_df['reg_month'],
        y=merged_month_df['month'],
        textposition='inside',
        textinfo='value+percent previous',
        marker={'color': '#44a9ff'}
    ),
    go.Funnel(
        name='Applications',
        x=merged_month_df['application'],
        y=merged_month_df['month'],
        textposition='inside',
        textinfo='value+percent previous',
        marker={'color': '#88c2ff'}
    ),
    go.Funnel(
        name='Game Plays',
        x=merged_month_df['game'],
        y=merged_month_df['month'],
        textposition='inside',
        textinfo='value+percent previous',
        marker={'color': '#c7e2ff'}
    )
]

# Create a dictionary with layout settings
layout = go.Layout(
    title='Funnel Chart of Sales Dynamics',
    funnelmode='stack',
    showlegend=True,
    legend=dict(x=1.0, y=0.8),
    xaxis=dict(title='Month'),
    yaxis=dict(title='Number of Visitors'),
    margin=dict(l=100, r=100, t=100, b=100)
)

# Create a shape and display it
fig = go.Figure(data=steps, layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

We get a funnel of this type:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U31Q7.jpg)
How do I make the percentages appear as a fraction of visitors to the site?
For example: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T2eb.jpg)

I tried changing textinfo='value+percent previous', it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

As you plot the data per column, I don't think you can get the % per row.
If you don't mind use plotly.express, there is an argument that allows you to define text.

Calculate the % in the data frame and then use plotly.express with the argument of text.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(month= ['2022-09','2022-10'],
                  visit = [778, 843],
                  reg_month =[186, 219],
                  app = [40,68],
                  game = [2, 21]))


df2 = df.melt(id_vars = 'month', var_name='Type')
df2['prct'] = 100 * df2.value / df2.groupby('month')['value'].transform('max')

#plot, assign 'prct' column of the dataframe to text argument
fig = px.funnel(df2, x = 'value',y = 'month',color = 'Type', text = 'prct')
#format text: value <next line> percentage %
fig.update_traces(textposition='inside',texttemplate="%{x:.0f\n}<br>%{text:.2f}"+'%')

for d,dc in zip(fig.data,['#3b78e7','#44a9ff','#88c2ff','#c7e2ff']):
    d.marker.color= dc
fig.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVr6a.png)